# PUGXMultiUserBundle: inject repository into registration form error

Tags: php, symfony, pugxmultiuserbundle

I would like to be able to inject a repository into a registration form (similar to [this approach](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-a-repository-instead-of-an-entity-manager/)) to use in an event listener but I get:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType::__construct() must >  be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\FocusRepository, string given, called in G:\Documents\workspace>  \match\vendor\pugx\multi-user-bundle\PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Model\UserDiscriminator.php on line 155

I can work around this in a template but using an event listener seemed a more elegant solution.  Any suggestions?

#### form

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType;
use AppBundle\Entity\FocusRepository;

class RegistrationType extends RegistrationFormType
{
    private $focusRepo;

    public function __construct(FocusRepository $focusRepo)
    {
        $this->focusRepo = $focusRepo;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
   ...
    }
   ...
}
```

#### service:

```
services:
    app.focus_repository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - AppBundle\Entity\Focus
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because PUGXMultiUserBundle uses FOSUserBundle registration (and profile) forms.  Those forms already have a string (indicating the class of User) in the constructor.  I've abandoned this question and am using a different approach.  But I now know that I perhaps could have used a Compiler Pass to override the FOSUserBundle registration form service to allow an additional parameter.  So a solution existed but was never tried.